# How can I activate b-tab on condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, bootstrap-vue

I am new in VUE3. I have an SVG image with some parts, data variable which is changing when click on particular part of the image and b-tabs. Is it possible to open specific tab depending on what is selected on the SVG image?

This is part of my code:

The SVG image

```
<rect
   @click="openTab"
   style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.264583"
   id="limitations"
   width="34.705162"
   height="32.925407"
   x="17.797518"
   y="49.83305" />
        data() {
        return {
            blockClicked: ''
        }
    },
```

This is my method:

```
methods: {
        openTab(block) {
            this.blockClicked = block.target.id;
            console.log(this.blockClicked);
        }
    }
```

I have tried with :active like this but it doesn't work:

```
<b-tabs pills card>
            <b-tab :active="this.blockClicked === 'limitations'">
                <template #title>
                    Limits
                  </template>
            </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean Bootstrap Vue [Tabs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs)

Use the `v-model` to control the Tabs externally ([External controls using v-model](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#external-controls-using-v-model))

```
v-model="tabIndex"
```

and

```
<b-button @click="tabIndex = 0">Tab 1</b-button>
```

Playground

```js
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { tabIndex: 0 }
  }
})
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
label { margin-left: 8px; }
```

```html
<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@^2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-tabs pills card v-model="tabIndex">  
      <b-tab title="First" active>
        First
      </b-tab>  
      <b-tab title="Second">      
        Second
      </b-tab>  
      <b-tab title="Third">
        Third
      </b-tab>  
  </b-tabs>  
  <hr/>
   <b>tabIndex:</b> {{tabIndex}}<br/>
    <b-button variant="outline-primary" size="sm" @click="tabIndex = 0">Tab 1</b-button>
    <b-button variant="outline-primary" size="sm" @click="tabIndex = 1">Tab 2</b-button>
    <b-button variant="outline-primary" size="sm" @click="tabIndex = 2">Tab 3</b-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. One more question. Is possible now in the opposite direction. When Tab2 is selected, some part which represents tab2 of the svg to be active(different style maybe)

Comment: @Scaldor `v-model` is bi-directional. Check this for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/75985575/2487565